# Match Object keys in array of objects and return key, values that have highest volume value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

> I have an array of objects, **baseAsset key**  and Volume are part of every object
>   but the volume is different for each object.
>
> I want to match the baseAsset key and return the object with the
>   highest volume value.
>   **Efficiency and speed is important as array have 3000+ objects**

```
let tickerA = [{
    pair: 'AUDUSD',
    baseAsset: 'AUD',
    lastPriceUSD: 0.74,
    volume: 1000
}, {
    pair: 'AUDUSD',
    baseAsset: 'AUD',
    lastPriceUSD: 0.76,
    volume: 2000
}, {
    pair: 'USDEUR',
    baseAsset: 'USD',
    lastPriceUSD: 1.25,
    volume: 1200
}, {
    pair: 'USDEUR',
    baseAsset: 'USD',
    lastPriceUSD: 1.19,
    volume: 1500
}]
```

> Expected return from a function

```
tickerB = [{
    baseAsset: 'AUD',
    lastPriceUSD: 0.76,
    volume: 2000
}, {
    baseAsset: 'USD',
    lastPriceUSD: 1.25,
    volume: 1500
}]
```

Comment: It's not clear why your desired result is for `USD` volume 1500 with a lastPriceUSD of `1.25` when your data has a `lastPriceUSD` of `1.19` on that item. Is that just a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in O(n) time by looping over and saving the largest item to an object. In the end your values will be in the `Object.values` of the groups:

```js
let tickerA = [{pair: 'AUDUSD',baseAsset: 'AUD',lastPriceUSD: 0.74,volume: 1000}, {pair: 'AUDUSD',baseAsset: 'AUD',lastPriceUSD: 0.76,volume: 2000}, {pair: 'USDEUR',baseAsset: 'USD',lastPriceUSD: 1.25,volume: 1200}, {pair: 'USDEUR',baseAsset: 'USD',lastPriceUSD: 1.19,volume: 1500}]

let groups = tickerA.reduce((largest, {baseAsset, lastPriceUSD, volume}) => {
    /* 
     * if it's a new baseAsset or bigger than a previous one, save it
     * to the group under the baseAsset key 
    */
    if (!largest[baseAsset] || largest[baseAsset]['volume'] < volume ) {
        largest[baseAsset] = {baseAsset, lastPriceUSD, volume}
    }

    return largest
}, {})

TickerB = Object.values(groups)
console.log(TickerB)
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to iterate the values of `tickerA` and map these to `baseAsset` keys if that item's `volume` value is greater than that of the current item of that `baseAsset` key:

```js
let tickerA = [{
    pair: 'AUDUSD',
    baseAsset: 'AUD',
    lastPriceUSD: 0.74,
    volume: 1000
}, {
    pair: 'AUDUSD',
    baseAsset: 'AUD',
    lastPriceUSD: 0.76,
    volume: 2000
}, {
    pair: 'USDEUR',
    baseAsset: 'USD',
    lastPriceUSD: 1.25,
    volume: 1200
}, {
    pair: 'USDEUR',
    baseAsset: 'USD',
    lastPriceUSD: 1.19,
    volume: 1500
}];

/* Use map to relate baseAsset key of tickerA item with current max volume value */
const map = new Map()

/* Iterate tickerA items, searching for greatest volume value per baseAsset class */
for(const item of tickerA) {
  
  const assetMatch = map.get(item.baseAsset);
  
  if(assetMatch && item.volume < assetMatch.volume) {
    /* If matching item (by asset found) with volume greater than that of current tickerA
    item, then disregard the current item */
    continue;
  }
  else {
    /* Otherwise, this tickerA item is; the first of the asset class, or greater in volume
    so we'll update the map entry for this asset class */
    map.set(item.baseAsset, item);
  }  
}
 
/* Extract the map values as an array */
const tickerB = Array.from(map.values());

console.log(tickerB);
```

Answer (score 0):

This alternative groups `baseAsset` and at the end extracts the grouped values.

*This is a `O(n)` time complexity*.

```js
let tickerA = [{pair: 'AUDUSD',baseAsset: 'AUD',lastPriceUSD: 0.74,volume: 1000}, {pair: 'AUDUSD',baseAsset: 'AUD',lastPriceUSD: 0.76,volume: 2000}, {pair: 'USDEUR',baseAsset: 'USD',lastPriceUSD: 1.25,volume: 1200}, {pair: 'USDEUR',baseAsset: 'USD',lastPriceUSD: 1.19,volume: 1500}];
let result = Object.values(tickerA.reduce((a, {baseAsset, lastPriceUSD, volume}) => {
    let {volume: current} = a[baseAsset] || {volume: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER};
    
    if (current < volume) a[baseAsset].volume = volume;
    else a[baseAsset] = {baseAsset, lastPriceUSD, volume};
    
    return a;
}, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` and `Object.values`:

```js
let tickerA = [{pair: 'AUDUSD',baseAsset: 'AUD',lastPriceUSD: 0.74,volume: 1000}, {pair: 'AUDUSD',baseAsset: 'AUD',lastPriceUSD: 0.76,volume: 2000}, {pair: 'USDEUR',baseAsset: 'USD',lastPriceUSD: 1.25,volume: 1200}, {pair: 'USDEUR',baseAsset: 'USD',lastPriceUSD: 1.19,volume: 1500}];
const res = Object.values(tickerA.reduce((acc, { baseAsset, lastPriceUSD, volume }) => {
  acc[baseAsset] = (!acc[baseAsset] || acc[baseAsset].volume < volume) ? { baseAsset, lastPriceUSD, volume } : acc[baseAsset];
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```